# How to define workbook/ worksheet and conditional copy and paste function

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to get a set of cells to copy and paste depending on the number inputted into a cell using VBA.

I was wondering if you could tell me why I am getting the error I am?

I am getting:

Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Thanks in advance

```
Sub layercopypaste()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Range(Cell1:="[L5:M9")

    If ("M4") = 2 Then
      Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9")
    ElseIf ("M4") = 3 Then
      Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9:L13")
    ElseIf ("M4") = 4 Then
      Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9, L13, L17")
    Else
      Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9, L14, L19, L21")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would either read the [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) documentation or do some searching online for how to reference ranges....

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

First you should use explicit references, so declare your worksheet(s).

Second you never actually use the range you set to a variable. It is also not the correct syntax. `Set rng = Application.Range(Cell1:="[L5:M9")` Remove `Cell1`, it is a named argument, but that isn't the correct usage. You also have a single bracket, you don't want any. You also don't need application.

Third you need range before all your ranges. `("M4")` will throw a syntax error.

Fourth in this situation `Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9")` and `Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9:L13")` will do the exact same thing, since the copy range is larger than the specified destination ranges.

Fifth I'm guessing you want to paste to multiple ranges with this line `Range("L5:M9").Copy Range("L9, L13, L17")` that will throw a syntax error, that is not a proper range. You need to use `Union` to do that. Though you will also get an error because the destination range overlaps the copy range.

Lastly this should probably be a `Select Case` not an `If`.

```
Sub layercopypaste()

    Dim myworkbook As Workbook
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    Set myworkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set mysheet = myworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Or whatever your sheet name is

    With mysheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("L5:M9")

        Select Case .Range("M4").Value
            Case 2, 3
                rng.Copy .Range("L9")
            Case 4
                rng.Copy Union(.Range("L11"), .Range("L17"), .Range("L23"))
            Case Else
                rng.Copy Union(.Range("L11"), .Range("L17"), .Range("L23"), .Range("L29"))
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```